# How to insert a button into a web page using IE via AHK

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to insert a button into a div on a page using IE and AHK.

This is what I have:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

wb := IEGet("Page1")
wb.document.all.external.innerText := "<input type=""button"" value=""Click Me!"" />"


IEGet(Name="")        ;Retrieve pointer to existing IE window/tab
{
    IfEqual, Name,, WinGetTitle, Name, ahk_class IEFrame
    {
        Name := ( Name="New Tab - Windows Internet Explorer" ) ? "about:Tabs" : RegExReplace( Name, " - (Windows|Microsoft) Internet Explorer" )
    }

    For wb in ComObjCreate( "Shell.Application" ).Windows
    {
        If ( wb.LocationName = Name ) && InStr( wb.FullName, "iexplore.exe" )
        {
            Return wb
        }
    }
}
```

The div has an id of "external".  I'm using IE 11, Win 8.1 and AHK 1.1.19.01.  The page title is "Page1".

When I run the above script, I don't get a button, but I get the html (as text) for a button.  Obviously converting the < and > to the relevant entity instead.

How do I get a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind - figured it out.  It's more of an IE DOM question than an AHK question.

This is how it's done:

```
wb := IEGet("Page1")

inp := wb.document.createElement("input")
typ := wb.document.createAttribute("type")
typ.value := "button"
val := wb.document.createAttribute("value")
val.value := "Click Me!"
inp.setAttributeNode(typ)
inp.setAttributeNode(val)

wb.document.all.external.appendChild(inp)
```